# How to "split" a function with two separate arguments of the form F[X][Y]?

Tags: function-construction

I recently stumbled upon a function `F[X][Y]`  that has two separate arguments X,Y. Note that it is not of the form `F[X, Y]`!

So for `F[X][Y]`,  first `F` acts on `X` and then `F[X]` acts on `Y`. Now for the purposes of my work I need to split the function `F = F1 + F2`, but I can't successfully feed the second argument `Y` neither `F1[X]` nor `F2[X]` in the end.

Here's my description in code:

```
F[X][Y]
% /. F -> (F1[#] + F2[#] &)
```

this gives as an output

```
(F1[X] + F2[X])[Y]
```

but what I need as a desired output is

```
F1[X][Y] + F2[X][Y]
```

So my question is:

How can one start from `F[X][Y]` so that one ends up with the desired output `F1[X][Y] + F2[X][Y]`?

Bonus question.

Can the above happen by only changing the head of `F?`, i.e., modifying the rule /. `F -> (F1[#] + F2[#] &)` somehow?

Comment: `% /. F -> (F1[#] + F2[#] &) // Through`

Comment: `% /. F[x_][y_] -> F1[x][y] + F2[x][y]`

Comment: Thank you both a lot for your fast answers, both of them work perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Just write it like any other function definition.

```
f[x_][y_] := f1[x][y] + f2[x][y]
```

Then

```
f[u][v]
```

gives

```
f1[u][v] + f2[u][v]
```

Answer (score 5):

To address the 'Bonus question':

```
F[subFs_List, args__] := Total[Through[subFs[args]]] /. h_[x_, y__] /; MemberQ[subFs, h] :> h[x][y]
```

Evaluating `F[{F1,F2},X,Y]` returns

> ```
> F1[X][Y]+F2[X][Y]
> ```

as expected

---

**edit:** The original answer above provided a solution in terms of `F` that doesn't work out-of-the-box, so to speak, when one *already* has an expression with terms involving `F`; in such a case, one can use `ReplaceAll`.

For the purposes of this amendment, consider an expression in `F` eg

```
expr = (a Log[F[X][Y]] - b /(c F[X][Y]) + d)^2 // Expand;
```

Then, `expr /. F[X][Y] :> F[{F1, F2}, X, Y]` returns, as expected:

> ```
> d^2 + 2 a d Log[F1[X][Y] + F2[X][Y]] + a^2 Log[F1[X][Y] + F2[X][Y]]^2 
>     + b^2/(c^2 (F1[X][Y] + F2[X][Y])^2) - (2 b d)/(c (F1[X][Y] 
>     + F2[X][Y])) - (2 a b Log[F1[X][Y] + F2[X][Y]])/(c (F1[X][Y] + F2[X][Y]))
> ```

### An alternative

In some cases, it might get confusing to have a *transformation* rule named after (having the same `Head`-sort of) the *expression* one is trying to transform; to tackle this problem, the transform can be conveniently renamed, as in

```
F /: expand[F[X][Y], subFs_: {F1, F2}] := 
  Total[Through[subFs[X, Y]]] /. h_[x_, y__] /; MemberQ[subFs, h] :> h[x][y]
```

This definition, attaches the transformation rule to `F` but avoids having `F[X][Y]` evaluate to anything in particular.

Here, it is assumed that `F[X][Y]` will be transformed using functions `F1` and `F2`. This can be changed by supplying a different argument for `subFs` eg it could possibly be the case that instead of two, it takes *three* functions `{F1, F2, F3}` to factor `F`.

Now, evaluating `expr /. patt : F[X][Y] :> expand[patt]` should return the same expression as above, namely

> ```
> d^2+2 a d Log[F1[X][Y]+F2[X][Y]]+a^2 Log[F1[X][Y]+F2[X][Y]]^2
>     +b^2/(c^2 (F1[X][Y]+F2[X][Y])^2)-(2 b d)/(c (F1[X][Y]+F2[X][Y]))
>     -(2 a b Log[F1[X][Y]+F2[X][Y]])/(c (F1[X][Y]+F2[X][Y]))
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In versions 11.1 through 12.0, [Curry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html) can be used to access the separate ("curried") arguments:

```
F[X][Y] /. F -> Curry[F1[#2][#] + F2[#2][#] &]

(* F1[X][Y] + F2[X][Y] *)
```

For historical reasons, the default form of `Curry` expects two arguments which it reverses.  So we have to write `F1[#2][#]` etc.  We can also explicitly specify the argument order, but it is slightly less concise:

```
F[X][Y] /. F -> Curry[F1[#][#2] + F2[#][#2] &, {1, 2}]
```

In version 12.1, `Curry` was renamed to [OperatorApplied](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OperatorApplied.html) (although `Curry` is still available but deprecated):

```
F[X][Y] /. F -> OperatorApplied[F1[#2][#] + F2[#2][#] &]
```

Version 12.1 also introduced [CurryApplied](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurryApplied.html) which allows us to explicitly specify the number of curried arguments (which do *not* get reversed or otherwise reordered):

```
F[X][Y] /. F -> CurryApplied[2][F1[#][#2] + F2[#][#2] &]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Through @ Operate[Apply[Plus @@ Through[{f1, f2} @ #] &], f[x][y]]
```

> f1[x][y] + f2[x][y]

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to realize that `Plus[a,b][c]` is actually not defined. So we can define it as we wish without changing much in the background mechanics of Mathematica.

With

```
Unprotect[Plus];
Plus[a_, b_][c_] := Plus[a[c], b[c]];
Protect[Plus];
```

we have what OP originally wanted:

```
(*In*)  F[X][Y]/.F->(F1[#]+F2[#]&)
(*Out*) F1[X][Y]+F2[X][Y]
```